# Dynamically set file path in log4rs

Tags: rust

I already asked this question in the Rust subreddit but wanted to ask it here too.

I'm using the [log4rs](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.13.0/log4rs/index.html) crate and want to find a way to generate more than one log file. I have a YAML file set up with the `file` appender created, and am trying to have the path be unique so it doesn't have to either append or truncate the original file.

```
appenders:
  file:
    kind: file
    path: "log/{h({d(%H:%M:%S)})}.log"
```

But this does not work and gives me this error:

`log4rs: error deserializing appender file: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)`

I know that `log4rs` has a way to do [patterns](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.13.0/log4rs/encode/pattern/index.html) but it doesn't seem to work specifically for the `path` parameter.

I also saw this other crate called [log4rs_routing_appender](https://docs.rs/log4rs-routing-appender/0.4.0/log4rs_routing_appender/) which looks promising but I don't know if I will need to use that.

Finally, **I want to be able to do this non-programmatically (i.e. only with one YAML file)**, and am wondering if it's possible within `log4rs`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize the `rolling_file` type make it so that it automatically increments numbers to the log names! This is the example of what I did.

```
appenders:
  default:
    kind: console
    encoder:
      kind: pattern
      pattern: "{h({d(%H:%M:%S)})} - {m}{n}"
  log_file:
    kind: rolling_file
    append: true
    path: "logs/log.log"
    encoder:
      pattern: "{h({d(%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S)})} - {m}{n}"
    policy:
      kind: compound
      trigger:
        kind: size
        limit: 10mb
      roller:
        kind: fixed_window
        base: 1
        count: 100
        pattern: "logs/log{}.log"

root:
  level: info
  appenders:
    - default
    - log_file
```

This generates log{}.log (replace {} with incrementing numbers) files within the `logs` folder after the file reaches 10MB of size. Since I set `append: true` the log file will keep accumulating until it reaches the size limit.

Hopefully this helps others too!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe what you want is possible with yaml configuration. However, log4rs provides another way to build it's logger, which is through `log4rs::Config::builder()`:

```rust
// get current date
let date = chrono::Utc::now();

// create log file appender
let logfile = FileAppender::builder()
  .encoder(Box::new(PatternEncoder::default()))
  // set the file name based on the current date
  .build(format!("log/{}.log", date))
  .unwrap();

// add the logfile appender to the config
let config = Config::builder()
  .appender(Appender::builder().build("logfile", Box::new(logfile)))
  .build(Root::builder().appender("logfile").build(LevelFilter::Info))
  .unwrap();

// init log4rs
log4rs::init_config(config).unwrap();
log::info!("Hello, world!");
Ok(())
```

I understand that you want to use YAML configuration. However, as you said, patterns do not seem to work with the path variable, seeing as writing this fails:

```yaml
path:
  pattern: "log/requests-{d}-{m}-{n}.log"
```

Another option would be to manually parse the yaml with `serde_yaml` ([which log4rs actually uses internally](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.13.0/src/log4rs/priv_file.rs.html#168)) and parse custom variables with regex.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt :)